# maximize a sum of unit fractions (without containing a subset of sum 1)

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, optimization

Let $ u \ge 2 $ be fixed. Then consider:

$ S(u)=\max\left\lbrace \sum_{i=1}^{u+1} \frac{c_i}{t_i} \, \middle| \, 2 \le t_1 \le t_2-1 \le \ldots \le t_{u+1}-1, \, t_i \in \mathbb{N}, \, c_i \in \mathbb{N}, \nexists a \in \mathbb{Z}^{u+1}_{\ge 0}, a \le c \, : \, \ \sum_{i=1}^{u+1} \frac{a_i}{t_i}=1 \right\rbrace $

Prove that $ S(u) \le \frac{\lfloor t_{u+1}+5 \rfloor}{3}$ holds. Is there perhaps a general formula for $ S(u) $ depending on $ u $ or $ t_{u+1} $? (I would doubt it.) Or are there better bounds than the given one?
Thanks a lot!